# Using drawContours OpenCV function in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed OpenCV 2.2 and when I try to use drawContours I get the following error:

```
cv.drawContours(frame, contours, 0, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0))
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

The code related to this error is the following:

```
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contours = cv.FindContours (color_mask, storage, method = cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv.drawContours(frame, contours, 0, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0))
```

The python documentation does not correspond with the correct order of parameters (I know the correct order thank to IDLE) and the C++ documentation for this function does not help me very much

Here is the full code (relevant code):

```
    cv.NamedWindow("MyWindow", 1)
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

    while 1:
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

        color_mask = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 1)

        cv.InRangeS(frame, cv.Scalar(*min_color), cv.Scalar(*max_color), color_mask)

        cv.CvtColor(frame, frame, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)

        storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
        contours = cv.FindContours (color_mask, storage, method = cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv.drawContours(image = frame, contours = contours, contourIdx = 0, color = cv.RGB(255, 0, 0))

        cv.ShowImage("MyWindow", frame)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be aware that drawContours and DrawContours are two different functions. They actually do the same thing, but they accept different parameters. I believe the first one only accepts numpy arrays instead of CvMat or other arrays from openCV.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the function parameters in the python reference of [DrawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc), and try not to rely on the order of the parameters when calling a function that takes multiple arguments, you should use labels.

In other words :

```
cv.DrawContours(img=frame, contour=contours, ...)
```

---

If you check the documentation of [`DrawContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc):

```
DrawContours(img, contour, external_color, hole_color, max_level, thickness=1, lineType=8, offset=(0, 0))
```

You will notice that the function accepts 8 arguments:

- 5 needed (img, contour, external_color, hole_color, max_level)
- 3 optional (thickness, lineType, offset)

and there are no arguments called `contourIdx` or `color`

eg:

```
cv.DrawContours(img=frame, contour=contours, external_color=cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), hole_color=cv.RGB(0, 255, 0), max_level=1 )
```

Comment: The right function parameters does not correspond with the official reference (I know this sounds stupid). If I do as you said the following error is raised: `TypeError: Required argument 'contourIdx' (pos 3) not found`

Comment: After a small break, I think the error could be in the contours generation

Comment: i think you are looking at the wrong documentation follow the link on the answer, its the documentation for the python API

Comment: I have read this documentation, but after download OpenCV 2.2.0 and compile & install it, if I open Idle, import OpenCV module and write cv.DrawContours, the parameters showed by Idle are not the same documented, I think the doc was generated before the final version. If I try to label parameters like 'img = wherever' the python interpreter raise and error saying there are any parameter with label 'img'

Answer (score 1):

Use the function cv2array and array2cv given on OpenCV Cheatsheet to convert the image to the specific format.

Something like this:

```
imgray = array2cv(cv2.cvtColor(cv2array(image), cv.CV_RGB2GRAY))
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contours = cv.FindContours(imgray, storage,cv.CV_RETR_LIST, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found some errors in Python wrapper of OpenCV 2.2. Examples like "*camshift.py*" run with OpenCV 2.1 but not with OpenCV 2.2. I suppose my problems are derivated from this bug (now I will use 2.1 version)

I have reported this bug as well as the documentation error

@P2bM thanks for your help